# Objective-C framework used in Swift - ambiguous use of method error

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, frameworks

I have an Objective-C framework where I've deprecated a method and replaced it with another one:

`+ (void)methodName:(BOOL)value;
+ (void)MethodName:(BOOL)value __attribute__((deprecated("from version 2.0 - use 'methodName'")));`

Which works fine in an objective-C project using the framework, but when I try and call that method in a Swift project I get the following error:

AppDelegate.swift:21:3: Ambiguous use of 'methodName'
[image]

(double clicking the ! Found this candidate line doesn't go anywhere)

The problem appears to be that the automatic conversion to Swift of the method names has a conflict with just the first letter being changed to lower case.

Is there any way I can wrap the deprecated method in a #if OBJECTIVE_C type pragma so that the Swift module only gets exposed to the one (newer) version of the method?

Or another way of working around the automatic translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both Objective-C methods are imported to Swift as

```
open class func methodName(_ value: Bool)
```

and that causes the ambiguity.

If the deprecated method should not be available in Swift at all
then you can annotate it with `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE`:

```
+ (void)methodName:(BOOL)value;
+ (void)MethodName:(BOOL)value __attribute__((deprecated("from version 2.0 - use 'methodName'")))
    NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE("deprecated method not available in Swift");
```

Another option is to annotate the deprecated method with `NS_SWIFT_NAME`:

```
+ (void)methodName:(BOOL)value;
+ (void)MethodName:(BOOL)value __attribute__((deprecated("from version 2.0 - use 'methodName'")))
    NS_SWIFT_NAME(oldMethodName(_:));
```

so that it is imported to Swift as

```
open class func methodName(_ value: Bool)

@available(*, deprecated, message: "from version 2.0 - use 'methodName'")
open class func oldMethodName(_ value: Bool)
```

See

- [Making Objective-C APIs Unavailable in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/making_objective-c_apis_unavailable_in_swift)
- [Renaming Objective-C APIs for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/objective-c_and_c_code_customization/renaming_objective-c_apis_for_swift)

for more information.

Comment: Thank you Martin R - I'm going with NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE for my specific case but it is great to see the other options available too, and the doc links (although Apple will no doubt move them all again in another year or two... ;-)